# Having two random generated natural numbers between 1 and 255, and generate out of it natural number between 1 and 256

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, dice

Let's say you have two cube with 255 sides and you have to use them to simulate a single cube with 256 sides, how can I do it?

$f(n)$ and $g(n)$ returns random number between 1 and 255.
I thought about: (Sorry for my programming background)

if $f(n) = g(n)$ then $h(n) = f(n) + 1$ else $h(n) = f(n)$, but it's wrong because it will have the first side to have about $1/256$ chance and it carries that $1/255/255$ to the next side (which makes them all $1/255$ and is wrong) every-time and the last will have $1/255/255$. Is there a way to make my way work? Or is there something else?

Comment: There is no way to do it in a single roll of the two cubes.  There are $255^2$ equally probable outcomes from rolling the two cubes, and $256$ doesn't evenly divide this number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(255(f(n)-1)+g(n)-1)\,\mathrm{mod}\,256+1$ also is close but not perfect, as Ross Millikan says, you need to reroll if the distribution is supposed to be perfect, afaik.

Comment: Still, we need need only reroll with probability $p < \frac{1}{256}$, so the expected number of rolls needed to produce a value is $< 1.01$, and this ought to be pretty good for most purposes.

Comment: I guess no answer is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

if $f(n) = g(n)$ then $h(n) = 256$ else $h(n) = f(n)$.

Edit: It has been proven wrong.

Comment: This won't generate all numbers with equal probability; $h(n)=256$ will be generated with probability $\frac1{255}$, while every other value will be generated with probability $\frac{254}{255^2}$.

Comment: This gives $1/255$ chance of $256$ and $1/255-1/(255^2)=624/65025$ for all the rest.  This is very close.  If you want exact, you will need to have a chance of rerolling as $256$ is not a divisor of the $255^2$